# How to force file numbering on saving?

Tags: windows-10

There are two kinds of saving dialog if I (or a software) try to save file with already existing name:

1. Alert is coming with `File with this name already exists. Do you want overwrite it?`. On `yes` the file is overwritten, on `no` saving procedure aborts.
2. The file is saved without any user action and is named as `already_existing_file_name (consecutive_number).fileExtension`, like `myfile (1).txt`

How can i force the second behavior, actionless adding of consecutiv number to the file name, on Windows10?

Comment: Short answer: You can't as although apps may use the common save as dialog they are free to change it's behaviour and many of them do.

Comment: @DavidPostill do i understand you correctly: software user is not able to change this behavior, but only the software author?

Comment: Yes, that's correct for the most part. It's possible to write hooks to override behaviour, but that involves you writing some Windows software to do so (which would be off topic here).